# Shout out to people for rescuing questions

Tags: discussion, badges

I wanted to publicly recognize a handful of people that no surprise are here to help. (And very effective at helping)

- https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/06/18/adios-to-unfriendly-badges-ahoy-lifejacket-and-lifeboat/

It’s good when a question gets down votes when it’s not useful, and then an edit (or first an answer and then an edit) and then raised above zero since it’s more useful with a good answer than it looked initially.

- https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/badges/258/lifejacket

We also have one golden badge to our lifeboat question of how to make a bootable installer.

- https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/badges/259/lifeboat?userid=22973
- [How to create a bootable Ubuntu USB stick using OS X 10.10.2](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/179781/how-to-create-a-bootable-ubuntu-usb-stick-using-os-x-10-10-2/)

Thanks to everyone that can make an answer so useful it raises the tide for the question and the answer. It’s easy to forget that a bad question (or one that looks bad) can still turn out good, that wrong answers can still help and that over time, the good can be found / edited / promoted to be a useful resource.